# Not getting the endpoint while exposing in kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes

I have deployed an app in Kubernetes, containers are created. But after some time, the pods are not running and it is showing errors like the `CrashLoopback` error.
I tried with the command `"kubectl describe svc <name>"`
But here I am not getting the endpoint. Can anyone please share the solution?

This is the error I'm getting,

```
PS C:\Users\panig\Downloads\dockerN> kubectl describe svc python
    Name:              python
    Namespace:         default
    Labels:            app=python
    Annotations:       <none>
    Selector:          app=python
    Type:              ClusterIP
    IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
    IP Families:       IPv4
    IP:                10.99.107.114
    IPs:               10.99.107.114
    Port:              <unset>  5002/TCP
    TargetPort:        5002/TCP
    Endpoints:
    Session Affinity:  None
    Events:            <none>
```

Comment: you need to describe pod, not the service. `kubectl describe pod pod_name`, why it in crashloop

Comment: I tried the command. it is showing terminated state,error exit code 1

Comment: can you add the describe output of the pod? plus `kubect logs -f pod_name`

Comment: PS C:\Users\panig\Downloads\dockerN> kubectl logs -f py-6467fbb598-kmqs2
check database details could not translate host name "poste" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

check database details could not translate host name "poste" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//api.py", line 19, in <module>
    base.autocommit = True
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'autocommit'

Comment: the application is not able to connect with database that's why it crashing

Comment: then what  is the solution for this ? Because I am getting the output in postman by running the dockerized file .

Comment: set the proper DB endpoint which is reachable from Kubernetes host

Comment: kubectl create deployment  pg --image=suchitra1/server:postgres   kubectl expose deploy pg --type=ClusterIP --port=5432   kubectl get pods
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pg-78d889f49-87b26      0/1     Error     2 (28s ago)   30s
react-c4596d7bf-8r9jr   1/1     Running   2 (87m ago)   24h
PS C:\Users\panig\Downloads\dockerN> kubectl port-forward pg-78d889f49-87b26  5000:5432 
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5000 -> 5432
Forwarding from [::1]:5000 -> 5432

Comment: I AM USING THIS PROCESS , BUT NOT GETTING THE ENDPOINT  AND HERE ALSO SAME CRASHLOOPBACK ERROR

Comment: if service in crash loop portfoward does not work, first the service or run simple nginx service to understand how thing work

Comment: ACTUALLY, first time I am deploying using kubernetes. Can you please help me to refer some link or course , which is helpful to solve this error.